# Spark K-means, points with there own cluster

Tags: cluster-computing, k-means, apache-spark-mllib

I am working on a project where I have to create a k-means model based on some training observations. I have 380 observations ( with 700 features). I am using the K-means algorithm from Spark MlLib. When I chose a k (number of clusters) greater than 10, some of my clusters only get 1 point assigned to them ( for example at 25, 6 of them get only 1 point). First I thought that some points have a big distance from the others, but the problem is that there are not always the same points that are assigned to there own cluster.

Is that an expected behavior? If it is a problem how big it is?

Answer (score 0):

This is typical for k-means.

In particular if you have many more features than data points, and if you have non-continuous features. It is a kind of overfitting - because of the high dimensionality, many points are "unique" in one sense or another.

Since k-means involves random, you don't get the same result every time.

You *need* to explore more advanced algorithms - k-means is really old and limited. Spark may not be the best tool for you, because it has so few algorithms to offer.